# Creating a 2D array with malloc and calloc

Tags: c, arrays

I am wondering how exactly this works and if this is even the correct way to do this. It works like I want it to. Basically what I'm doing is creating a float array where all elements are 0 with the height of h and width of w.

```
float** arr = NULL;
arr = (float**) malloc(sizeof(float*) * h);
for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i) {
    arr[i] = (float*) calloc(h, sizeof(float) * w);
}
```

Comment: That is a good way to create a [*jagged array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's not really what I was going for here though

Comment: A jagged array doesn't have to be "jagged". You can still use it as a "2d" array or a matrix.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Okay but that doesn't really answer my question.. Is this the correct way to create a 2d array of floats where every element is equal to zero?

Comment: It's *one* way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you want a 2D array - jagged array - with size `h` x `w`

Then you need something like:

```
float** arr = NULL;

size_t h = 2;
size_t w = 3;

arr = (float**) malloc(sizeof(float*) * h);  // 1)
for (size_t i = 0; i < h; ++i) {
    arr[i] = (float*) calloc(w, sizeof(float));  // 2)
}
```

Note 1) - allocate `arr` that points to an array size `h` of pointers to float.

Note 2) - allocate each item `arr[i]` that points to an array size `w` of float.

As usual, you should use `size_t` type instead of `int` for array size.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks. Quick question, would it be fine to use `arr = (float**) calloc(h, sizeof(float*));`?

Comment: Yes, the effect is the same. But use `malloc` in the first call would be more efficient because you don't really need to zero out the content of `arr[i]` pointer, you only need to clear the content of what `arr[i]` points to. In other words, the 2nd call to `calloc` is necessary, but the 1st is not.